# Typescript getter type inference

Tags: typescript

Typescript seems to be inferring field types strictly based on the private variable of a field.
However, it won't complain if the getter returns a type union (1), nor will it infer the actual type from the getter (2):

```
    test('field type inference', () => {
  class A {
    x_: number;

    // 1: no type checking here
    get x(): number | undefined {
      if (this.x_ === 1) return undefined;
      return this.x_;
    }

    set x(v: number | undefined ) {
      this.x_ = +v;
    }
  }

  const a = new A();
  a.x = 1;

  // 2: The inferred type is number (as of x_, instead of getter)
  const x: number = a.x;

  console.log(a.x) // outputs 'undefined'
})
```

Is this specified / expected behavior?

Later edit. Note that `strictNullCheck` will not catch this either. The only two it will are missing initialization and setter

The following example with `strictNullCheck` warnings fixed:

```
test('field type inference', () => {
  class A {
    x_: number;

    get x(): number | undefined {
      if (this.x_ === 1) return undefined;
      return this.x_;
    }

    set x(v: number | undefined ) {
      this.x_ = +(v ?? 0);
    }

    constructor(value: number) {
      this.x_ = value;
    }
  }

  const a = new A(2);
  a.x = 1;

  const x: number = a.x;

  console.log(a.x)
});
```

Comment: You probably don't have `strictNullChecks` enabled as compiler option, in which case TS drops all `undefined`/`null` types from unions.

Comment: I think I do, but why does it matter since strictNullCheck is simply treating the possible null dereferencing as error whereas, here, it's not *inferring* the actual type. I.e. strictNullCheck has nothing to catch. The only thing that strictNullCheck will catch is that I would need a constructor to initialize x_. However if I do add the constructor, it won't catch this - again, because it's an inference issue.

Comment: `strictNullChecks` will _not_ catch the missing initialization in the constructor, that's what `strictPropertyInitialization` is for. As I mentioned, TypeScript simply drops `undefined` from any type union if `strictNullChecks` is not set (please verify whether that is enabled or not). The getter/setter pair's type have to be identical, but are completely independent from private field `x_`.

Comment: I understand. However in practice , it does. The two errors that I see with `strictNullCheck` are possibly indefined cast att setter 
solved with:
`
    set x(v: number | undefined) {
      this.x_ = +(v ?? 0);
    }
`

and  missing constructor, solved with
`
    constructor(value: number) {
      this.x_ = value;
    }`

Nevertheless I'll update the post to clarify

Comment: Oh, I see now! Actually, that looks like a bug/limitation in flow typing, where the assignment to `a.x` is assumed to be the value that is read when assigning into `x`, but with getters/setters that is definitely unsound narrowing behavior! You might be able to find an issue report for this behavior in the TypeScript Github repo.

Comment: I just wen through the issues. I can't find this, but reading [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2521) makes me thing this is a bug

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221535/discussion-between-joost-and-cosmin-lehene).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, when you have properties typescript assumes that reading from the property will retrieve the value last written to that property. You getter/setter here breaks that convention. But because each get/set function is technically typesafe on it's own, typescript doesn't notice anything wrong.

Second, when you assign a constant to a property typed as a union, typescript remembers which member of that union applies for the rest of that scope. The fact you have logic in those getters/setters doesn't matter.

It's got nothing to do with the private property, and everything to do with the public one.

Let's say you had this very simple class:

```
// No getters/setters
class B {
  x: number | undefined
}

const b = new B()
b.x // number | undefined
b.x = 1
b.x // number
```

As you can see, typescript remembers what you've assigned, knows it's not undefined, and then strips that from the resulting type of the property in any where it can know that to be true.

---

Now let's try this class:

```
// useless getters/setters
class C {
  get x(): number | undefined {
    return undefined;
  }

  set x(v: number | undefined ) {
    // no-op
  }
}

const c = new C()
c.x // number | undefined
c.x = 1
c.x // number
```

Now the getters/setters are useless, but it gives you the "wrong" results.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEDkHtQcwUwC4LgJwM7DY56BQBjAGwEM01QAhUAb11FAA8AuUAOwFcBbAI1VAB9Q7VgBM4AMwCWrOCNwBfApFZoEobqAC8bOAHdKACgCUubgDoGoEGy68UAoaInTZpi1tABGN5esceqLi41uxYhHBksNioGFhIMQQkkQDCNHRRagzGLP52DsJiUjIiafT0KIjsKKyOhS4iANzpiulxjAYAbjm2fIIFzsWgRqVlfpAAtJAADs0KQfjKqqD4HjL6ycYE7n499n1ORa747trex75guahAA)

---

Typescript expects a getter to return the last set value if that last value was set in the same synchronously executed scope. In fact most programmers probably would, too.

Ideally the compiler would flag an issue with something here, but tracing the type safety through these setters is actually a pretty complex thing to do.

Comment: Related to the quote from TS#2521, the .d.ts emit has changed in TS 3.7 so that's no longer a blocker for allowing getters/setters to have different type (although that restriction is still true today). See breaking changes note in https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-7/

Comment: Thank you Alex and @Joost! Both of your arguments were on point!

The original code would have flagged it if `strictNullCheck` would have been on (@Joost)
The example wasn't because of the *Second* point.